# Cardinality of strategy space of $G_{\omega}(\mathbb{R})$ up to an equivalence relation

Tags: cardinals, game-theory

Suppose, in  $G_{\omega}(\mathbb{R})$, a player's two strategies are equivalent, if, for any strategy of his opponent, the outcome incurred are the same. It can be shown that in $G_{\omega}(\omega)$ and $G_{\omega}(2)$, the cardinalities of partition of strategy spaces derived from equivalence relation are $2^{\aleph_0}$, since cardinality of set of strategies that are constant functions(which are not equivalent)and that of strategy space are both $2^{\aleph_0}$. But in $G_{\omega}(\mathbb{R})$,the cardinalities of two corresponding sets are $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

---

(Apologize for just copy and paste some content from the question I asked before)

---

Formally,  a two-player game $$G(\omega,(X_n)_{n \in\omega},(Y_n)_{n \in\omega},)$$ where

- $\omega$ is the number of the moves of each of the two players I and II.
- $(X_n)_{n \in \omega}$ (or $(Y_n)_{n \in \omega} $) is a $\omega$-sequence of $X_n$(or $Y_n$), which is the action space of $n$th move of first (second) player.
- The game is played in an alternating fashion.An outcome is a $\omega$-sequence:$$a_0 \in X_0, a_1 \in Y_0, a_2 \in X_1, a_3 \in Y_1, a_4 \in X_2……$$
- A player moves at any stage contingent on history. So a strategy for player I take the form as s sequence of functions $\{\sigma_i\}_{i \in \omega}$:
  $$\sigma_i : \prod_{j<i}{X_j \times Y_j} \to X_i$$ Player II's strategy's form $\{\tau_i\}_{i \in \omega}$is defined similarly. Player I and Player II's strategy spaces are denoted as $S_{\text I}$ and $S_{\text {II}}$ respectively. Denote the binary operation $\star$ as the function that sends a pair of strategies of player I and player II to the outcome they give rise to.
- Player I and Player II's strategy spaces are denoted as $S_{\text I}$ and $S_{\text {II}}$ respectively. Denote the binary operation $\star$ as the function that sends $\sigma$ and $\tau$, a pair of strategies of player I and player II to the outcome $a$ they give rise to$$\sigma \star \tau \mapsto a$$
- Strategy $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ for player I are equivalent, if for any player II's strategy $\tau$, $$\sigma \star \tau = \sigma' \star \tau$$ The equivalence class $[\sigma]$ is denoted as$\{\sigma' \in S_{\text{I}}:\forall \tau \in S_{\text{II}}(\sigma \star \tau = \sigma' \star \tau)\}$, and the corresponding partition of $S_{\text{I}}$ as $S_{\text{I}}'$. We define the equivalence relation for Player II in the same way.

What is cardinality of $S_{\text{I}}'$, when $X_n = Y_n = \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ pairwise inequivalent strategies for player II (and it's easy to modify them to work for player I instead).  Fix two distinct reals $x$ and $y$. For each set of reals $A$, let $\sigma_A$ be the strategy for player II that outputs $x$ on the first turn if Player I's first move is in $A$, and $y$ otherwise.  On each subsequent turn we let $\sigma_A$ output $x$.

Comment: Aleph and alpha are both he first letters of their respective alphabets, and they represent the same sounds. But they are not the same, more so mathematically. :-)

Comment: @Asaf Oops, I always do that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Asaf I need a keyboard with $\aleph$ on it so I don't have to type something so similar to "alpha".

Comment: Oh, you still have to type \aleph. LaTeX and Hebrew aren't very good friends... :-)